# Keep row and col names while use normalize.quantiles

Tags: r, normalization

I have a data frame with row and col names, see below

```
set.seed(123)
dat<-data.frame(expand.grid(c("A", "B"), LETTERS[1:4]), 
           matrix(sample(40), ncol = 5))
rownames(dat)<-LETTERS[1:8]
```

I use `normalize.quantiles` to normalize the data

```
library(preprocessCore)
n.dat<-normalize.quantiles(as.matrix(dat[ 3:ncol(dat)]))
```

The problem is after normalization `row col names` disappear.
How can I keep it without renaming rows and columns?

Comment: It's not a easy solution it seems. I haven't heard/used this package before. I was going through the source code for this [here](https://github.com/bmbolstad/preprocessCore/blob/master/R/normalize.quantiles.R#L31) . Every thing is fine in there, until it calls a C function [here](https://github.com/bmbolstad/preprocessCore/blob/master/src/qnorm.c#L2178) and this is where it looses it's dimnames. We need to change the source code in the C function there to retain the row and column names. OR OR OR just do `dimnames(n.dat) <- list(rownames(dat), colnames(dat)[3:ncol(dat)])` after running :P